# Compiler warnings plugin: Fileset excludes

Tags: ant, hudson, fileset, clover

We are using Hudson as our build machine and I am trying to configure the excludes fileset for the Compilier Warnings plugin. Hudson parses the build log to determine warnings/errors and our Clover scripts output duplicates of real warnings.

As documented by Hudson you can configure an ANT fileset to exclude certain warnings:

```
  Warnings to ignore:: Fileset 'excludes' setting that specifies the warnings to exclude from the report (based on their filename).
```

I am getting the following warnings (duplicates):

```
C:/vsfz/temp/1/clover1710786373818922904.tmp/src4952837385592305293.tmp/corp/app/path
....
```

I have set the excludes fileset to:

```
*vsfz/temp/*/clover*/**
```

I expected the Fileset to match the warnings and for them not be added to the Compiler Warnings report, this is not the case. Does anyone see a problem with the above Fileset definition?

Comment: Thanks Bernie & Peter, I will give this a go (when I get back to work on Monday) and will update this question with results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this going (it has been on the back burner for quite some time now).

The template that I ended up using:

```
**/temp/**
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

`C:/vsfz/temp/*/clover*/**`

or

`**/vsfz/temp/*/clover*/**`

another problem might be that `clover*` doesn't match correctly so that you have to write it as `clover*.*` but I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: \*\*/vsfz/temp/*/clover*/*\* did not work unfortunately; I am trying with *.* for tonight's build.

Comment: So far I have had no luck, I will continue testing and report back when I find anything that works.

Answer (score 0):

I was just messing with this today and I could only get it to work when I specified the file extension`*.cs`or maybe `*.*` would work?

anyway `**/old*/**/*.cs`  worked for me.

Hope this helps.